# pdf not uploading in newfile but word is uploading

Tags: php, html

There are similar questions, but none helped me, so please help me.
I am trying to upload pdf format in a file using php, but it is not uploading. But with the same code word document got uploaded. What's the problem? How to fix it?

```
<html> 
<form action="addbook.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="pdffile" type="file"</div>
<input type="submit" name="myfile">
</form>
</html>
```

Below code is addbook.php

```
<?php
$pdf=$_FILES['pdffile'];
$doc=$pdf['name'];

$pdftemp = explode(".", $pdf["name"]);
$newpdfname = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($pdftemp);
move_uploaded_file($pdf["tmp_name"], "propic/" . $newpdfname);
?>
```

I expect pdf file to get uploaded in the file called propic.

Comment: Do you get any error? Please var_dump($_FILES) to check if the file was uploaded. And close the tag on your <input>

Comment: no, I am not getting any error @CarlosAlvesJorge. The problem is that Word document is getting uploaded but not pdf.

Comment: Please var_dump($_FILES) to see is the files was uploaded to the php or if it doesn't even reach there. If one file is uploaded and the other isn't probably is because of the size of the files (PHP has a limit for file upload) but it would be nice to make sure.

Comment: I think this should work, its weird

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge, where to add var_dump($_FILES) ? I added it in addbook.php in fourth line. But nothing is showing.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help! pdf file below 200kb is uploading. File size issue is there. How can i upload big pdf like of 10mb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you upload any small size of pdf file like 200 KB etc. If it's worked then file size issue.

you have need to increase upload_max_filesize.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Shivendra pdf file like below 200kb is uploading. How to upload pdf like 10mb?

Comment: Can anyone give exact syntax for increasing file size upload? and where to write it?

Comment: to increase the upload_max_filesize edit the php.ini file, search for 'upload_max_filesize' and update the size on based on requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much @shivendra, you are a life savior. It worked. Thank you so much.